# Show: Linear mapping or none

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could someone explain me if the following is a linear mapping or none:
$$\text{Of }f:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3} \text{ is known: }$$
$$f(\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix} 5\\3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$f(\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\\5 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$f(\begin{pmatrix}-3\\2\\7 \end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix} 9\\3\\-7 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: The question is: Can you find a (regular) matrix that represents this transformation? This matrix is a 3 by 3 matrix and you can actually try to find this matrix by performing 3 matrix multiplications using the givens

Comment: $f$ is a linear map if $f(\mathbf u+\mathbf v) = f(\mathbf u)+f(\mathbf v)$ and $f(a\mathbf u) = af(\mathbf u).$  Can you express one of the vectors in the domain as a linear combination of the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not linear, because $3\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}-2\pmatrix{3\\2\\1}=\pmatrix{-3\\2\\7}$ but $3\pmatrix{5\\3\\1}-2\pmatrix{1\\3\\5}\ne\pmatrix{9\\3\\7}.$

Answer (score 0):

No such $f$ can be linear. Indeed, if to the contrary $f$ was linear, then on one hand
$$f(3\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix})=3f(\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix})-2f(\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}13\\3\\-7\end{pmatrix}$$
but on the other hand the LHS equals
$$f(\begin{pmatrix}-3\\2\\7\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}9\\3\\-7\end{pmatrix}.$$